# select product details page options if dropdown has one value in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, product-view, configurable-product-options

I want to select the options in each dropdown in product details page if it has one option. 
for **example**

```
dropdown : 1 (option)
dropdown : 2 (option)
dropdown : 1 (option)
```

Then on the selection of the first drop down, the second drop down will be active for selection and when we select an option from the second drop-down then if the third drop down has only one option then it has to be selected as default

Answer (score 0):

i have written this code in this file --> `Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable.js (pub/static path)` under the function "`_fillSelect:`" and after the "`if (options)` " condition close.

```
if (options.length == 1) {
                   this.options.values[attributeId] = options[0].id;
            }
        if (element.options.length == 2)
        {
            element.options.selectedIndex = 1;
        }
```